# Показ инфраструктурных объектов на карте (школы, дет. сады, магазины, аптеки и т.д.)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Прошу помочь советом в решении такой задачи: имеется карта с нанесенным на нее объектом недвижимости. Необходимо показать вокруг инфраструктурные объекты, которые могут привлечь внимание потенциального покупателя к объекту (это коротко про бизнес-задачу :). Изучил АПИ поиска поиска по организациям - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/response_structure_business-docpage/, в принципе, можно дать запрос и в text перечислить необходимые типы объектов "text=школа,детский сад,магазин,гипермаркет,автосалон" и т.д.. На такой запрос АПИ возвращает данные, проверил, но получается, что придется дополнительно наносить все эти объекты на карту и рисовать для них какие-то свои обозначения, иконки и т.д. Это очень кропотливая и большая задача.

Вопрос такой: неужели нельзя непосредственно самой яндекс.карте "сказать" при инициализации: покажи слой с организациями такого типа... И все организации вывелись бы в дизайне самих карт, как при поиске по ней, с иконками и балунами при клике... Примеров в апи карт не нашел (может плохо искал)? Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Такой возможности нет, вы всё правильно описали про использование API Поиска по организациям, с той только разницей, что на каждую категорию нужно делать отдельные запросы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, жаль, что нет. Но в целом я заметил, что на большем масштабе яндекс по умолчанию показывает такие инфраструктурные объекты - сады, школы, храмы, магазины, аптеки... Это может быть выходом. К тому же мы не влезем, скорее всего, в лимиты бесплатной версии при отдельных запросах на каждую категорию...

Comment: В HTTP API разрешено не более 500 бесплатных запросов в сутки, да, для такого сценария правда не лучший выход